# What is the difference between code that causes a deadlock vs one that prevents it? Need explanation for code example

Tags: java, deadlock

I'm given code of a Banking example and I'm trying to figure out if this does produce a deadlock or not. If so, what part of the code achieves it? I would also like to know how I would alter the code to prevent deadlocks. I know it has something to do with the ordering of the methods but this code specifically confuses me. I'm new to networked programming so I'm still a little confused on this topic.

I have written this in Java.

public class Bank 
{

```
public Bank(int n, double initialBalance)
{
    accounts = new double[n];
    Arrays.fill(accounts, initialBalance);
    bankLock = new ReentrantLock();
    sufficientFunds = bankLock.newCondition();
}

public synchronized void transfer(int from, int to, double amount) throws InterruptedException
{
     bankLock.lock();
     try
     {
        while (accounts[from] < amount)
           sufficientFunds.await();
        System.out.print(Thread.currentThread());
        accounts[from] -= amount;
        System.out.printf(" %10.2f from %d to %d", amount, from, to);
        accounts[to] += amount;
        System.out.printf(" Total Balance: %10.2f%n", getTotalBalance());
        sufficientFunds.signalAll();
     }
     finally
     {
        bankLock.unlock();
     }
}

public synchronized double getTotalBalance()
{
    bankLock.lock();
     try
     {
        double sum = 0;

        for (double a : accounts)
           sum += a;

        return sum;
     }
     finally
     {
        bankLock.unlock();
     }
}

public int size()
{
    return accounts.length;
}
```

public class DeadlockApp 
{

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Bank bank = new Bank(NACCOUNTS,INITIAL_BALANCE);
    for (int i = 0; i< NACCOUNTS; i++)
    {
        int fromAccount = i;
        Runnable r = () -> 
        {
            try 
            {
                while (true) 
                {
                    int toAccount = (int) (bank.size() * Math.random());
                    double amount = MAX_AMOUNT * Math.random();
                    bank.transfer(fromAccount, toAccount, amount);
                    Thread.sleep((int)(DELAY * Math.random()));
                }
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
            }
        };
        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.start();
    }
}
```

When I ran the code it was very slow and only produced two results so I couldn't tell if it was the deadlock that was going continuously or my IDE was just lagging.

Comment: Well, you seem to execute the events sequentially rather than a concurrent manner,  and make use of synchronized, so in first sight I am not sure about the deadlock. What was the expected output and what was the result you got ?

Comment: @KoralpCatalsakal The program was just supposed to transfer random amounts between accounts, print it out, and do it continuously, but because of the locks, it slowed down. My professor said that this was a correct way to make deadlocks, but I did not understand why completely. And I would like to know how I can change the code to prevent deadlocks as well.

Comment: It’s very strange to combine implicit locks with  reentrantlock, do one or the other, not both. As it stands this isn’t really causing deadlocks. Not every error resulting in hung threads is a deadlock.

Comment: @NathanHughes I was initially getting negative balances when I wasn't implementing this code, which isn't supposed to happen. When I added the reentrantlock it stopped doing that

Comment: Agreed - there's no need for two locks; pick either.  Also, you could reduce the time any lock is held;  I think you only need the wait for sufficient funds, and the subtraction from one account and adding to another under the lock. Move the print statements to before or after the synchronized code.

Comment: When you await it frees the reentrantlock, but not the implicit lock the thread acquired when it entered the method, and there’s no way for a second thread to enter the method. You’re basically sleeping forever holding a lock. That’s not a deadlock, just a mistake.

Comment: If your program completed, there was no deadlock. Unclear what you're really asking here.

Answer (score 0):

The basic requirement for deadlocking is that two or more threads attempt to acquire a series of locks, but acquire them in varying order.

You have two locks in play, but your threads are all executing the same code, which has a fixed order of lock acquisition, and both locks can be recursively acquired, so there's no deadlock.

More specifically, only one thread at a time is executing in `transfer` by virtue of it being `synchronized`.

The locks are acquired in this order:

1. The Bank monitor (by 'synchronized' on transfer)
2. banklock (in transfer)
3. The Bank monitor again ('synchronized' on getTotalBalance) - but we hold it already so it will not block
4. banklock (in getTotalBalance) but we hold it already so it won't block

No deadlock, so there's some other cause for 'slowness'.  My guess would be on how long the random actions take to build up sufficient funds.